# Parallel or Concurrency? Java Concurrency name problem

Tags: java

I learn from a cookbook that there is the main difference between the words: Parallel and Concurrency.

- Parallel: working on multiple tasks with multiple cores / CPUs
- Concurrency: working on multiple tasks with one core / CPU but with the time-framing mechanism.

So I also learned that Java is the language that using the power of multiple cores to achieve multiple task processing simultaneously. But its package name on this ability is called `java.util.concurrency`.

Why does java use the word concurrency instead of Parallelism?

Comment: there is no `java.lang.concurrency` package, but `java.util.concurrency`.
By the definition, the contents of said package are concurrent, not parallel.

Comment: Concurrency isn't necessarily restricted to one core. Concurrency is the concept that tasks should be able to run while other tasks are waiting (`async` / `await`, for instance). It can be done on one core, or it can be distributed to several.

Comment: The package name is `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that definition of "concurrency" is correct.

The definition provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) is:

> "In computer science, concurrency is the ability of different parts or units of a program, algorithm, or problem to be executed out-of-order or at the same time simultaneously partial order, without affecting the final outcome. **This allows for parallel execution of the concurrent units**, which can significantly improve overall speed of the execution in multi-processor and multi-core systems. In more technical terms, concurrency refers to the decomposability of a program, algorithm, or problem into order-independent or partially-ordered components or units of computation."

In other words, concurrency *includes* parallelism.  (Or at least, the kind of parallelism you get with multiple conventional CPUs or hyperthreads.)

The article goes into more detail, and gives literature citations for the introduction of the term.

Furthermore, what the Wikipedia article says is consistent with the way that other sources use the term "concurrent"; e.g. Java: Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz et al.

---

> Why does Java use the word concurrency instead of Parallelism?

Java is correct in using the term concurrent / concurrency.

The mistake is in the "cookbook" you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency and parallelism are orthogonal.

You can have parallelism without concurrency e.g. single thread running on a CPU with super scalar execution, instruction pipelines and SIMD instructions.

You can have concurrency without parallelism; e.g. a bunch of threads running on a system with a single CPU (executing instructions sequentially).

Often concurrency enables parallelism. E.g. if you have split up the processing logic so that parts can be run concurrent using different threads, then often these threads can be run parallel using different CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

According to my superficial knowledge, Java's multitasking is based on the **JVM multithreading model**; while **parallelism is more based on the task parallelism in the physical concept of the CPU**. It is difficult for Java to control the CPU to achieve task parallelism, and it can only guarantee more The threads are concurrent.